# NodeJS: How to make multiple HTTP requests concurrently every 3 seconds?

Tags: node.js, long-polling

Given an array of `location_ids`, I want to make a request to `https://connect.squareup.com/v1/{location_id}/payments` every 3 seconds for each location_id.

Is the best way to do this through long polling and socket.io? (I've never used it).

Or are there other ways to do this? Would like some insight. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Long polling would be better suited for such unattended remote calls.

Comment: And is the most popular solution for nodejs `socket.io`?

Comment: Yes it is the most popular, use `socket.io` as it reduces the HTTP overheads and creates a peer-to-peer connection between the 2 endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

Socket.io is a two way protocol which needs to be configured on **both** your machine and on connect.squareup.com. If this option is available then you should be able to emit/listen events (for example : notify me when a payment arrives a this location.)

If this option is not available and you are still planning to work with node.js you could achieve that with the request module and the good old setInterval function.

[NodeJs Timers](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html)

[NPM Request module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request)